# How can I define a simple non-method function on wren?

Tags: scripting, wren

The documentation of the wren scripting language http://wren.io/ explains how to define methods within a class, but I want to define a simple function and not a method. I tried this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env wren
square(n) {
        return n * n
}

System.print(square(3))
```

and this (omitting the parts other than the attempted function definition:

```
var square= {|n|
        return n * n
}
```

and this

```
var square= Fn.new {|n|
        return n * n
}
```

but nothing worked.

Any advice how I could make it work without resorting to method definitions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: Obviously I forgot the invoke the call() method on the function object. This works:

```
#! /usr/bin/env wren
var square= Fn.new {|n|
        return n * n
}
System.print(square.call(3))
```

However, I find it hard to believe that all user-defined functions have to be called by explicitly invoking a "call" method on them!

The last time I have seen something like that where "call" had to be written explicitly all the time was TI BASIC for the TI-99/4a.

But that was about 35 years ago! ;-)

Comment: This had been discussed before: https://github.com/wren-lang/wren/issues/711. In short, Wren is classes-first and can not support this syntax.

Comment: It does not support this ATM, but will be added. Check github, I think there is an issue, otherwise make one.